# CQ user is not getting added into group using Java in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I am trying to add a cq user in AEM a group. I using below code. Code running successfully but the user is not getting added into the group. Can you please see where I am doing a mistake?

```
 ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
              UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
            try {
                Authorizable authGroup= userManager.getAuthorizable("administrators");
                LOGGER.info("authorizable"+authGroup.toString());

                Group group = (Group) authGroup;
                Authorizable authUser = userManager.getAuthorizable("myuser");
                LOGGER.info("Before Groufp"+authUser.toString());
                boolean b=group.addMember(authUser);
                LOGGER.info("After Group"+authUser.toString());
                if(b){
                    LOGGER.info("success");
                }
                else{
                    LOGGER.info("failure");
                }


            } catch (RepositoryException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: There is a article by aem, about how to create users and group: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-jackrabbit-usermanager-apis-6.html#, Hope this helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `userManager.autoSave(true)` or you can add a `finally` block and in there you can do:

```
Session session = userManager.adaptTo(Session.class)
if(session != null){
   session.save()
}
```

read about UserManager here: https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html